# Time complexity of associative arrays in shell scripts

Tags: algorithm, shell, scripting, associative-array, time-complexity

I would like to know how an associative array is constructed/implemented when used in shell scripts.

Also, I want to know if the time complexity of shell script based associative arrays are optimal since we can use alphabets as well as numbers as their respective keys.

EDIT: what hash function do they use??

Comment: take ksh for an example. ksh93 to be precise.. This is a very generic question that I would like to ask for all shells though

Comment: You can't ask it for "all shells" - it's implementation specific.

Comment: @Brian: okay, in that case I would like to know about the ksh93 in specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an associative array, you're not accessing it via "use alphabets as well as numbers as their respective keys"; You're using strings - any numbers are the character representations, not an actual index.

I can't find anything concrete short of looking through the source, but by most accounts it appears that internally it's implemented as a hash table (rather than a tree) so your access and insert average time is going to be O(1). Doesn't get much more optimal.

Comment: @Brian: So how does the look-up function work with a string. Suppose one of the key is " I am the look-up key" and another key is "I am the other look-up key". How does the internal data structure accomdate such a big string ? Secondly, is there a limit to the string size?

Comment: You probably want to read the wiki entry on [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for the answer to how it works. As for the length of the key, that would be specific to ksh93 and I can't find anything that lists it. I would imagine reasonably long, and it will prob just truncate anything that's too long.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks a lot for the help. I am familiar with has tables and I am trying to look up the associative array implementation in Solaris. I dont really know where to look for it. Thats the reason I put this question in StackOverflow. I am trying to find the hash function the developers have used to map the key to its respective memory location. Thanks again

Comment: I googled all over with no luck. Best way would be to download the source for ksh and look at it. It is now available, http://www.kornshell.com/software/

Comment: To answer your first question (sorry, I missed it) - it doesn't store strings so it doesn't have to accomodate anything. It just hashes the string to get a numerical result within the bounds of the array. They do say an array is limited at 4096 items, so the hashing algo is going to spit out something between 0 and 4095