# Mapping ids for 10 million records

Tags: bash, shell

I have two text files,

File 1 with data like

User game count

```
A Rugby 2
A Football 2
B Volleyball 1
C TT 2
...
```

File 2

```
1 Basketball
2 Football
3 Rugby
...
90 TT
91 Volleyball
...
```

Now what I want to do is add another column to File 2 such that I have the corresponding index of the game from File 2 as an extra column in File 1.

I have 2 million entries in File 1. So I want to add another column specifying the index(basically the line number or order) of the game from file 2. How can I do this efficiently.

Right now I am doing this line by line. Reading a line from file 1, grep the corresponding game from file 2 for its line number and saving/writing that to a file.

This will take me ages. How can I speed this up if I have 10 million rows in file 2 and 3000 rows in file 1?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a database for this ?

Comment: No, there is no reason. I have it in the form of text file.

Comment: You've asked the very same question before - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20602644/45375 - and have received answers. If these don't work, modify your question and/or start a bounty.

Comment: Ok, inserting 10 million rows to a standard SQL DB in that format should not take more than ~60 seconds. You insert the the data to two  tables (users-gameName-gameCount, game-gameID) and then make a query that `JOIN`s the talbes on gameName - to get user-gameName-gameCount-gameId. That should be done in a few minutes.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum. Are you sure it doesn't take more than 60 seconds?? I tried to import that to mysql and it's already 10 min and still running importing

Comment: @user34790 then you've configured something wrong. Doing the math, the whole data should take about 500M in memory, so actually running it in-memory might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum. I have loaded everything into database like you said. However, the join operation is like taking for ever. I have this huge game table with 10 million records and this other file 1 with like 2000 records. I did the JOIN operation like this "SELECT game.id FROM game RIGHT JOIN player ON game.game_name=player.game_name"

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), read field 1 from `File2` into an array indexed by field 2, look up the array using field 2 from `File1` as you iterate through it

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$2]=$1; next}; {print $0, a[$2]}' File2 File1
A Rugby 2 3
A Football 2 2
B Volleyball 1 91
C TT 2 90
```

Comment: How much time would this take on 10M rows?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I haven't measured it but it is likely a lot faster than the OP's grep loop. The core part, the array lookup, is `O(1)`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Roughly a little longer than reading each file once, plus some overhead for printing the matches. If there are only a few matches, not much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an associative array from the second file, with game names as keys and the game index as values. then for each line in file 1 search the array for the wanted id, and write it back

[Associative arrays provide O(1) time complexity.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710249/254170)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` command:

```
$ cat file1
A Rugby 2
A Football 2
B Volleyball 1
C TT 2

$ cat file2
1 Basketball
2 Football
3 Rugby
90 TT
91 Volleyball

$ join -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2 \
      <(sort -k 3 file1) <(sort -k 1 file2)

B Volleyball 1 Basketball
A Football 2 Football
A Rugby 2 Football
C TT 2 Football
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach: only read the small file into memory, and then read the bigger file line-by-line. Once each ID has been found, bail out:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        f1[$2] = $0
        n++
        next
    } 
    ($2 in f1) {
        print f1[$2], $1
        delete f1[$2]
        if (--n == 0) exit
    }
' file1 file2
```

---

Rereading your question, I don't know if I've answered the question: do you want an extra column appended to file1 or file2?